# Given $\cos C(\sin A +\sin B)=\sin C \cos(A-B)$, prove that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, examples-counterexamples

> Given $\cos C(\sin A +\sin B)=\sin C\cos(A-B)$, prove that triangle $ABC$ is equilateral.

My attempt:

> By applying some trigonometric identities, I have:
>    $$\cos C(\sin A +\sin B)=\sin C \cos(A-B)\\
> \iff \cos C \cdot2\sin \frac{A+B}{2} \cos \frac{A-B}{2}=\sin \frac{C}{2}\cos \frac{C}{2}\cos(A-B)\\
> \iff \cos C  \cos \frac{A-B}{2}=\sin \frac{C}{2}\cos(A-B)\\
> \iff \left( 1-2\sin^2 \frac{C}{2}\right)\cos \frac{A-B}{2}=\sin \frac{C}{2}\left( 2\cos^2 \frac{A-B}{2}-1\right)\\ \iff \cos \frac{A-B}{2}+\sin \frac{C}{2}=2\sin \frac{C}{2}\cos \frac{A-B}{2}\left(\sin \frac{C}{2}+\cos \frac{A-B}{2} \right)\\ \implies 2\sin \frac{C}{2}\cos \frac{A-B}{2}=1$$
>   or $$2\cos \frac{A+B}{2}\cos \frac{A-B}{2}=1$$
>   or $$\cos A +\cos B=1.$$

And that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same result!

Now take $A=30^{\circ}$, for example,  and we see that our triangle is not equilateral.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Dave Robin I mean that it's impossible to prove that our triangle is equilateral. Take $A=30^{\circ}$ and we got a counterexample.

Comment: Do you mean taking $A=B=C=60^\circ$?

Comment: I mean take $A=30^{\circ},$ $B=\arccos\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)$ and $C=150^{\circ}-\arccos\left(1-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right).$